# How to get key and value of jsonobject from jsonarray?

Tags: android, json

I have a json like this :

```
{
  "FindingMedia": [
    {
      "ScheduleDetailID": 12414,
      "AnswerId": 2,
      "findID": 2,
      "mediaID": 3,
      "Files": "xxx",
      "ExtFiles": "jpg"
    },
    {
      "ScheduleDetailID": 12414,
      "AnswerId": 2,
      "findID": 2,
      "mediaID": 4,
      "Files": "xxxx",
      "ExtFiles": "jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I get the key and the value to inserting into my sqlite in android?

I've a code like this :

```
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(parsing);
        for(int i=0;i<jsonObject.length();i++)
        {
            JSONArray jsonArray= jsonObject.getJSONArray("FindingMedia");
            db.addContact(new Contact(jsonArray.toString()));
            Log.d("json", jsonArray.toString());
        }
```

the output of log is:

> [{"MediaID":3,"ExtFiles":"jpg","ScheduleDetailID":12414,"Files":"xxx","ExtFiles": "jpg"}]

but the output of log have a sign `[` and `{`

How to get the output without a sign like above?

like

> "MediaID":3,"ExtFiles":"jpg","ScheduleDetailID":12414,"Files":"xxx","ExtFiles": "jpg"

EDIT :

contact class:

```
public class Contact {
    int _id;
    String _name;

    public Contact(){

    }
    public Contact(int id, String name){
        this._id = id;
        this._name = name;
    }

    public Contact(String name){
        this._name = name;
    }

    public int getID(){
        return this._id;
    }

    // setting id
    public void setID(int id){
        this._id = id;
    }

    // getting name
    public String getName(){
        return this._name;
    }

    // setting name
    public void setName(String name){
        this._name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `JSON` parsing is wrong

Try this

```
        try {
           JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(parsing);
            JSONArray jsonArray= jsonObject.getJSONArray("FindingMedia");
            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject object=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.d("AuditScheduleDetailID", object.getString("ScheduleDetailID"));
                Log.d("AnswerId", object.getString("AnswerId"));
                Log.d("findID", object.getString("findID"));
                Log.d("mediaID", object.getString("mediaID"));
                Log.d("Files", object.getString("Files"));
                String data="mediaID: "+object.getString("mediaID")+"ExtFiles: "+object.getString("Files")+"ScheduleDetailID: "+object.getString("ScheduleDetailID"); 
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: no row in sqlite and i get an error in logcat about `W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for findID`

Comment: @flix can you share that **db.addContact** function with question

Comment: my db getting from [here](https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) but i just deleted phone, and editing name type from `text` to `blob`, because i want to store bash64

Comment: @flix share your **Contact** class i will update my ans as per your requirement

Comment: @flix try this **`String data="mediaID:"+object.getString("mediaID")+"ExtFiles:"+object.getString("Files")+"ScheduleDetailID:"+object.getString("ScheduleDetailID");`**

Comment: what you mean about `json parsing`? do you mean about my json in string?

Comment: @flix as per your out put request in the question

Comment: my String parsing is `String parsing = "{\"FindingMedia\":[{\"ScheduleDetailID\":12414," +
            "\"AnswerId\":2,\"findID\":2,\"mediaID\":3," +
            "\"Files\":\"xxx\"ExtFiles\":\"jpg\"}]}";

Comment: that's work sir, thanks for the help, you save my day

Comment: @flix happy to help you enjoy codding

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(parsing);     
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("FindingMedia");
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject e = null;
    try {
        e = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String strAnswerId= e.getString("AnswerId");
        String strFindID= e.getString("findID");

    } catch (JSONException e1) 
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: @flix your `JSONArray` is ROOT here.Try this way.